# Slide automático con ViewPager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager

estoy creando un Slide usando ViewPager el cual puedo cambiar de vistas al deslizar el dedo, pero la ayuda que busco con esta pregunta es saber como puedo generar el movimiento de manera automática y si es posible me oriente en como agregar algúna animación a esta transición como cuando configurámos las animaciones de unas diapositivas para presentación en PowerPoint.

A continuación les muestro el código, agradezco la ayuda.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.tecnologias.uniagustapp.viewpagerlobelo.MainActivity">
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
 </LinearLayout>
```

**swipe_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/image_count"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;
CustomSwipeAadapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new CustomSwipeAadapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

**CustomSwipeAadapter**

```
public class CustomSwipeAadapter extends PagerAdapter {

private int[] image_resource = {R.drawable.img01,R.drawable.img02,R.drawable.img03};
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public CustomSwipeAadapter(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return image_resource.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
    return (view == (LinearLayout)o);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout,container,false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    TextView textView = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_count);

    imageView.setImageResource(image_resource[position]);
    textView.setText("Imagen : "+(position+1));
    container.addView(item_view);

    return item_view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
}
}
```

Tambien he compartido el proyecto aquí: **[ViewPager](https://github.com/ivanlobeloc/ViewPagerLobelo)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewPager tiene un metodo llamado [`setCurrentItem(index, hacerTrancisionSuave);`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int,%20boolean)) que te permite desde el codigo seleccionar la pagina que desees indicandole el indice al que desea que navegue el ViewPager:

```
viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new CustomSwipeAadapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
```

En este ejemplo el ViewPager navega a la pagina que esta en el indice 1 por defecto. Ya solo tendrias que adaptar tu codigo para que lo haga de manera programada.
El ultimo parametro indica si quieres hacer la transicion entre paginas con efecto o no.

Comment: Gracias, tienes algún tutorial que me ayude adaptar el código?

Comment: He agregado una respuesta donde uso el metodo setCurrentItem(int index), no encontré diferencia usandolo con los parámetros  setCurrentItem(index, hacerTrancisionSuave); **[Respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/116502/34903)**

Answer (score 1):

Por ahora he agregado un temporizador que me permite hacer una transición entre cada vista, sin embargo no es la solución que estoy buscando ya que lo que busco es generar algún tipo de animación entre las trancisiones, a continuación comparto el código.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;
CustomSwipeAadapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new CustomSwipeAadapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    //viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(), 2000, 4000);
}

public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask{

    @Override
    public void run() {

        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if(viewPager.getCurrentItem()==0){
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    //viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
                }else if(viewPager.getCurrentItem()==1){
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                    //viewPager.setCurrentItem(2, true);
                }else if(viewPager.getCurrentItem()==2){
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    //viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```